# Quartz JobStoreSupport recoverMisfiredJobs Handling 3 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have a quartz application that works well on other environments.

But when we deployed it in a clustered environment with two needs, it stopped working. All I can see are tons of the log shown below.

Any ideas what may have caused it? I am sure it's not our code since it never went through any TaskHandlers.

```
[7/17/14 13:14:54:236 EDT] 00000025 JobStoreTX    I org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport recoverMisfiredJobs Handling 3 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
```

**Updated :**

I'm suspecting it maybe due to the transaction isolation level configuration. Currently the quartz data source is configured to TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED (CS). Any suggestion on the appropriate value?

Also the TRIGGERS table shows it never fired:

| NEXT_FIRE_TIME | PREV_FIRE_TIME | PRIORITY | TRIGGER_STATE | TRIGGER_TYPE | START_TIME | END_TIME | CALENDAR_NAME | MISFIRE_INSTR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1405630189133 | -1 | 5 | WAITING | CRON | 1405624813000 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1405630189139 | -1 | 5 | WAITING | CRON | 1405624813000 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1405630215140 | -1 | 5 | WAITING | CRON | 1405624813000 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1405630189126 | -1 | 5 | WAITING | CRON | 1405624813000 | 0 |  | 0 |

Comment: how you solve this problem ?

Comment: The problem is not in quartz. There are some logic problems that causes the threads to get blocked.

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Comment: If you have 10 quartz threads that the triggers are utilizing, and the trigger is set to fire every second. When the trigger code takes too long to execute, i.e. 1 minute, then after 10 triggers, the threads run out, which blocks the succeeding triggers. Thus, causing the miss fires. This is just my observation after doing some tests.

Answer (score 1):

> Handling x Trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time

is primarily due to the thread pool being exhausted. Check if multiple instances of a job are in running state

Comment: I increased this setting from 2 to 10 in quartz.properties file and misfire message is gone. org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10

Answer (score 0):

Either your job implements `org.quartz.StatefulJob` or you might have the annotation `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`.

This will make the scheduler wait until the previous job triggered via the same scheduler is complete so that there is no overlapping.

I would suggest either increasing the time between two consecutive jobs or changing the `org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold` property.